# Ação durante a rolagem do browser

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho o seguinte HTML:

```
  <section id="rolagem">

    <article id="item1">

     //conteúdo
   </article>

   <article id="item2">

    //conteúdo
  </article>

   <article id="item3">

    //conteúdo
  </article>
</section>
```

O que preciso fazer em javascript puro para que, a cada vez que eu rolar a barra de rolagens para cima, ela oculte um item a partir do item1.

Grato a quem ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Manipulando elementos com Scroll da página em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108313/manipulando-elementos-com-scroll-da-p%c3%a1gina-em-javascript)

Comment: Não consegui usando o código dele

Comment: Tem até o exemplo funcionando no *codepen*: https://codepen.io/silviolucenajunior/pen/bErJgm
Só mudar o valor de `window.scrollY`